# Application of triangular inequality

Tags: linear-algebra

Given $\alpha_j$, $\beta_j$ real (positive or negative) with $j=1,2$ and $M>1$ real, the following

$\sqrt{(M^2-1)\alpha_j^2-\beta_j^2}$ have to be real, so, $\left |\beta_j\right |<\left |  \alpha_j\right |\sqrt{M^2-1}$

What can be said about $\beta_1-\beta_2$? I know the answer but can't get it on my own.

Comment: You can use this : $|\beta_1-\beta_2| \le |\beta_1| + |\beta_2|.$

Comment: Could you elaborate on that? Thanks

Comment: It's triangle inequality. Because $|x-y|=|x+(-y)| \le |x|+|-y| = |x|+|y|.$ Are you clear now?